# Implement folder sharing in a php/mysql application with multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/mysql application. There are users who have folders. Folders can only be one level deep. Each folder can have unlimited number of documents. The relevant tables are as follows:

**user_table:**

```
user_id(PK), name, password, etc
```

**folder_table**:

```
folder_id(PK), name, user_id(FK into user_table)
```

**document_table**

```
document_id(PK), user_id(FK), folder_id(FK), date, name, etc
```

All queries to operate on folders and documents are of the form

```
select/update/insert <blah, blah, bhah>
where user_id = %d
```

Now, I'm looking to allow users to share they folders with other users. I want to do this in the least disruptive way possible. I also want to minimize run time overheads of resulting WHERE clause.

I've been wracking my brains and googling but haven't found a simple enough solution. I can think of implementing it in a manner similar to unix's (read, write, execute) along with (owner, group, others) mechanism. But it seems a bit too complicated for my humble system.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me pointers as to which approach I could possibly take. My goals are simple:

1. The system doesn't require a whole lot of reworking
2. At a minimum users should be able to share folders with other users or groups (I
   will add concept of groups if needed)
3. There should not be too much overhead in SQL statement's WHERE 
   clause as opposed to what it is now (as simple as: `WHERE
   user_id = %d`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sharing folder(s) with user(s)

You can to add a table *folder_user* with columns `folder_id(FK), user_id (FK)`

The `user_id` in *folder_table* represents the owner of the folder. When the owner shares this folder with another user, you add folder_id and user_id (with whom folder is shared) into `folder_user` table.

Later, you can add column `access (enum 'READ', 'READ_WRITE')` to the same table, to see if a user is allowed to edit documents in the folder or not.

### Sharing folder(s) with group(s)

1. You need a table *group*
2. Then you need to add users to groups, so add a table *user_group* : `user_id(FK), group_id(FK)`
3. Then, to give access to of a folder to a group add table *folder_group*: folder_id(FK), group_id(FK) to give access for a folder to a group.

Comment: This sounds like a plan with minimal overhead. Thanks.